# Silverlight DataForm validation Custom Mandatory

Tags: silverlight, validation, dataform

I'm using a Dataform with X number of fields. At the moment I'm attaching the [Required] tag to the Properties I want setting as mandatory which is working well.

However I need to toggle the mandatory state was on say a selection in a combo box. for example In the combo box if I select Item1 checkBox's 1,4 and 6 are mandatory. Selecting Item 2 means checkboxs 2 and 3 need to be mandatory.

Any tips

Comment: You'll need to look at custom validation at the class level. Then you can check the value of the combo box when validating the checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

USE IDataErrorInfo approach for validation . This approach will help you to handle  this kind of validation situation.

[This Link](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2010/08/15/validating-data-in-silverlight-4-applications-idataerrorinfo.aspx) will help you to unserstand this approcah.